# Random matrix with conditions

Tags: php

I want to print random numbers in the table like the picture below.

[image]

1. 18 rows and 9 columns
2. exactly 5 numbers by row
3. 1st column (1-10), 2nd column (11-20) until 90. (1-90)
4. cannot have duplicated numbers in there

When I refresh the page, numbers should be changed (numbers position). I already did it, but some few rows goes wrong and doesn't fill condition 2 (with less than 5 numbers).

```
<?php
  
function getAllColumnIndexes() {
    $tmpCols = [];
    $columnIndexes = [];
    
    for ($l = 1; $l <= 9; $l++) {
        $indexes = [];
        $arr = range(1,18);
    
        while (count($indexes) != 10) {
            shuffle($arr);
    
            if ( empty($arr) ) {
                break;
            }
            
            $i = array_shift($arr);
            
            if ( !isset($tmpCols[$i]) ) {
                $tmpCols[$i] = 0;
            }
    
            if ( !in_array($i, $indexes) ) {
                if ( $tmpCols[$i] < 5 ) {
                    $indexes[] = $i;
                    $tmpCols[$i] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    
        shuffle($indexes);
        $columnIndexes[$l] = $indexes;
    }
    
    return $columnIndexes;
}
    
$numberList = [];
$startVal = 1;
$endVal = 10;

for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $numbers = range($startVal, $endVal);
    shuffle($numbers);
    $numberList[$i] = $numbers;
    $startVal += 10;
    $endVal += 10;
}
    
$columnIndexes = getAllColumnIndexes();
    
?>
    
<table>
    
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 19; $i++) {
    echo '<tr class="active">';
    
    #ROW
    for ($j = 1; $j < 10; $j++) {
        $num = '';
    
        #COLUMN
        $rowNumber = $i;
        $colNumber = $j;
    
        $tmpIndex = array_search($rowNumber, $columnIndexes[$colNumber]);
    
        if ($tmpIndex !== false) {
            $num = array_shift($numberList[$j]);
        }
    
        echo "<td>{$num}</td>";
    }

    echo '</tr>';
} ?>
</table>
```

Demo link: https://soap2day.vipembed.com/num-table.php

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show only the exact concise code to reproduce your problem instead of the entire project.

Comment: Can you precise ` some few rows goes wrong.` ?

Comment: What does _"each row max & minimum 5 numbers"_ means? min 5 or max 5 or always 5?

Comment: @vee it should be always 5

Comment: @Ôrel It does not fill 5 numbers each row always. you can check demo site. It should be fill 5 numbers always in each row, but 2-3 rows do not fill correctly.

Comment: It's a logic problem: you assume that if you fill random positions in the first rows, you will end with at least a possibility to fill the last rows, but this assumption is wrong. See this [counter-example](https://3v4l.org/1NCO4). I think there's something to do with permutation matrix.